# variance of iid random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

As been said in this question [iid variables, do they need to have the same mean and variance?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223373/iid-variables-do-they-need-to-have-the-same-mean-and-variance) the answer is yes, but I'm looking for the proof for that for general random variables, not for continously or discrete random variables.

So the question is, why do iid random variables have the same parameters, mean, variance?

Thanks in advance
Chaim

Comment: Because they have the same distribution? It's like asking: why is $17-17=0.$

Answer (score -1):

"iid" stands for "independent, identically distributed". If random variables are identically distributed, they must come from the same distribution. A distribution that has a mean and variance has a unique mean and variance. If random variables come from a common distribution, they are identically distributed, and they must have a common mean and variance.

To be more mathematical, let's say $X_n$ is a sequence of random variables, independent and identically distributed from a distribution I'll call $\mathcal{D}$:
$$
X_n\sim\mathcal{D}
$$

The distribution $\mathcal{D}$ has an associated density function, let's call it $f_D(x)$, with mean given by
$$
\mu = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf_D(x)dx
$$
and variance given by
$$
\sigma^2 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(\mu-x)^2f_D(x)dx
$$

Note that with the appropriate use of delta functions in $f_D$, this can represent a probability mass function for discrete variables as well, so this applies in either case.

By definition
$$
\mathbb{E}[X_n]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf_D(x)dx=\mu
$$
and
$$
\text{Var}[X_n]=\mathbb{E}[(X_n-\mu)^2] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(\mu-x)^2f_D(x)dx=\sigma^2
$$
So, if variables are iid, they have the same mean and variance. This extends to all higher order moments as well. The key word is "identical".

Comment: Nice try, but what's the point?

Comment: Maybe boredom? I dunno, I just want to get through. Repetition is key to learning.

Comment: Also, gives me TeX practice.

Comment: @rajb245 To explain it with continous or discrete random variable is not my problem, as I said in my question. my problem is with general rv

Comment: With the appropriate interpretation of $f_D$, the above is valid for BOTH discrete and continuous random variables. If you have a problem understanding why this is so, please let me know and I can clarify my answer. To say a bit more, any "general" random variable is either continuous, or discrete. The above is valid for both cases, therefore, it is valid for "general" random variables. Do you have a specific question about the validity of the above I can address for you? If so, I can clarify further.

Comment: It notably FALSE that a "general" random variable is either continuous or discrete. [There exist random variables which escape this categorization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4418038/what-is-an-example-of-a-measure-without-a-density-that-is-useful-for-some-applic/4418066#4418066). @rajb245 you may want to delete the last comment and possibly generalize your answer.

Comment: @Snoop That is an interesting point I hadn't considered. To the OP and future readers: I'll just reiterate that the formulas above are valid and show that the expectation and variance of the IID variables are written as a specific integral over the PDFs, and because all the variables have the same PDF, they have the same values of those integrals. Not all RVs are strictly continuous or discrete, but the continuous framework with delta functions allowed is general enough to capture the cases the OP was concerned with, and with the mixed case Snoop points out.